# wordpress // working with github, deploying, etc…

Tags: wordpress, plugins, deployment, production

What would a wordpress expert would recommend to develop robustly, and deploy things in production ? Tools to recommend ?

I'm looking for a setup or tools that experienced wp devs use

Thanks for sharing

Comment: Not sure if it is a joke or not (:

Comment: hahaha I honestly though it might help, apparently not! are you looking specifically for tools for working with github then?

Comment: Sorry I was being a bit sarcastic. Damn it wp users… Not sure I'll find what I'm looking for right here

Comment: Perhaps this might help a bit more - https://plausiblethought.net/wordpress-git-workflow/ - this dude lists some tools for this exact thing. I thought about doing something like this a few years ago. But in the end thought it would just create more work, as working with wordpress is tedious enough as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [wp-gear.org](http://wpgear.org/) under section Build scripts

some reference:

WP Stack - Capistrano deploy

Capistrano-WP - Alternative Capistrano deploy

WordPhing - Phing/Php build script

YeoPress - Yeoman

Grunt-WP-Plugin - Grunt (node)

Varying Vagrant - Varying Vagrant Vagrants for WP

VCCW - Vagrant designed for development of WordPress plugins, themes, or websites

Puppet WordPress - Puppet

Composerpress - Retroactively creates a composer.json for WP

Grunt-WP-Deploy - Grunt to deploy a build directory to WordPress SVN

Bedrock - Gets you started with the best development tools,practices, and project structure